# I want to randomly choose 20 questions from an array and check the answers, but the system won't show the questions

Tags: java

My code is like this... All the questions cannot be the same....But when I try it, it will repeat the same question again and again. or, it will not show the questions that all....

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Questions extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] questionsdone = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 };
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
            int ramNum = rnd.nextInt(30);
            //randomly choose a number between 0 to 30
            int checkingSize = 0;
            for (int z = 0; z < questionsdone.length; z++) {
                if (questionsdone[z] != ramNum) {
                    checkingSize++;

                    if (checkingSize == 20) {
                        questionsdone[i] = ramNum;
                        String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, questions[z], "Grade 11 Computer Science Review Exercise", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                        //show the questions
                        if (answer.equals(answers[z])) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct! The answer is " + answers[z], "Grade 11 Computer Science Review Exercise", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                            mark = mark + 1;
                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong! The answer shuold be " + answers[z], "Grade 11 Computer Science Review Exercise", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    }
                    //check the answers
                    if (questionsdone.length == 20) {
                        break;
                    }

                } //end if
            } //end for
        } //end for
    }
}
```

Comment: all the questions are in the questions array and answers are in answer array...

Comment: I recommend reading through a style guide to help you with code formatting. [Oracle Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html) or [Google Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html)

Comment: I suggest you write code to fill an array with 30 random, non-repeated numbers, and then use that array to drive the rest of your program.

Comment: nextInt(30) returns numbers form 0 to 29 not 30 just keep that in mind.

Comment: @theVoid: An arrangement that would be quite suitable for a 30 element question array.

Comment: yea but in his comment he states that the return number is from 0 to 30.I do not say that what he did is wrong.

Comment: One issue: `questionsdone.length` will always return the same value; the length of the array never changes. I didn't count the array elements but assuming there are 20, `questionsdone.length == 20` will always be true.